# High Level Explanation

Tags: high-level

I am doing a project for school and the question says

> "Prepare a high-level explanation of the interface for the user. The user is the intended audience of this explanation, so the code is not relevant. "

How do I provide a high level explanation without using some kind of code?

Comment: High level means that you don't need to worry about lower level implementation details.

Comment: Try using your favorite human language, maybe English.

Answer (score 0):

I find that a lot of software is sorely missing "high level explanation".  Modern programming languages tend to make the code fairly easy to understand at the microscopic level; and comments on methods and properties in interfaces can help the user with detail about how to use the interface.  However, the user needs to first understand the **overall domain concepts and design approach** before the detailed documentation can be useful.  Pulling those concepts out of detail comments and the code can be difficult.  High-level explanation can help the user tremendously.